# Ruby 2.2 Using REXML

Tags: ruby, rexml

I have followed much tutorials about Ruby 2.2 and REXML. This is an example of my xml:

```
<msg user='Karim'><body action='ChkUsername' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>
```

And this is what I currently have as code:

```
        xml =    "<msg user='Karim'><body action='ChkUsername' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>"
        doc = Document.new xml
        puts doc.root.attributes[action]
```

That won't work. An error pops out. undefined local variable or method 'action' for #{classname} (NameError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't randomly assume variables exist. The token `action` will be interpreted as a reference (e.g., a variable or method call) since it's not a string or symbol. You don't have that variable or method, so you get an error telling you precisely what's wrong.

```
puts doc.root.attributes['action']
```

The root of your document is the `<msg>` tag. The `<msg>` tag does not *have* an attribute `action`. It has a `user` attribute, accessible as you'd expect:

```
 > require 'rexml/document'
 > xml = "<msg user='Karim'><body action='ChkUsername' r='0'><ver v='153' /></body></msg>"
 > doc = REXML::Document.new(xml)
 > doc.root.attributes['user']
=> "Karim"
```

The `action` attribute is nested further in the document, in the `<body>` element.

There are a number of ways to interrogate a document (all covered in the tutorial, btw), e.g.,

```
 > doc.elements.each('//body') do |body|
 >   puts body.attributes['action']
 > end
ChkUsername
```

Comment: how could I call the action attribute then?

Comment: @Jad ... How I told you to in the answer?

Comment: oh okay sorry. This still gives undefined local variable or method 'action' for #{classname} (NameError)

Comment: @Jad That is not possible; `action` is an immediate string in the code in my answer.

Comment: How is that not possible? Maybe I am not accessing the attribute properly?

Comment: Nevermind. It seems I had a problem elsewhere. Now, this doesn't even give the value of action. It gives nothing. No errors show.

Comment: @Jad Because there's no `action` attribute at the root of the document. I'm not sure if you're being serious here or not; I'm amending my answer to pretend like it's a tutorial. I'd seriously consider actually doing a REXML tutorial, though, it seems like you're trying to skip a few steps.